# Why there are 2 definitions for high level logic input in the following datasheet?

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, power-sequencing

I was referring a power sequencer datasheet at

https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/sites/default/files/slg7nt4618_ds_r024_03102016.pdf

Iam confused with 2 definitions for the high level (circled below). Can anyone please clarify which one I have to consider?

[image: Confusing spec]

Comment: It seems that they are saying what level is "low" at VDD=3.3V. Between 1.13 and 1.78 the input can probably be considered "floating" in that it may be undefined behavior or "stick" at the last value. It outlines the same thing for 1.8V and 5.0V too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip has different types of input pins. The datasheet pin list says pin types are Digital Inputs and Low Level Digital Inputs. They are different and thus have different input thresholds.